# 502 proxy error between load balancer and openam

Tags: tomcat, mod-proxy, openam

We have a system where we have two openams behind an apache httpd load balancer. The load seems to be balanced evenly from looking at the logs, both openams have roughly 35k requests in a time frame. Though 1 openam sent around 100k requests to the other in that same time frame and only received 93k back.

In terms of the OpenAM attributes we have the following

- Session persistence and HA failover Enabled: true
- Reduced Crosstalk Enabled: true
- Session Logout/Destroy Enabled: Disabled
- Reduced Crosstalk Purge Delay: 1

We have noticed that one OpenAM is using roughly 3 times the amount of RAM than the other (4.5gb compared to 1.5gb). The load balancer reports 502 proxy errors for the OpenAM that is using the more RAM and receiving the more requests from the other. These happen roughly every 20 or 30 minutes.

The proxy timeout from the httpd balancer is left to default which I think is 30 seconds. I have monitored the number of connections each OpenAM has and they both seem to be the same, roughly around 30.

The machines have plenty of RAM available and we haven't limited the amount of heap that tomcat will use. OpenAM is deployed in tomcat8 container and running java8.

Can anyone think of any reason why 1 OpenAM would need 3 times the amount of RAM and also be timing out when the load balancer tries to connect? All help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Reduced crosstalk mode in versions around 13.0.0 wasn't always working as well as it should have, so one suggestion would be to disable that.

It's difficult to tell why a certain node would consume more RAM, you should consider running jmap against the heavy process to try to identify whether you are dealing with a memory leak or something else.